# SDWebImage error for loading image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, sdwebimage

When I am trying to load image using SDWebImage,it's showing error like

> < No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:'>

I am trying to load the image in a imageview in tableview cell like this:

```
[newsImage.image sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[jsonResult[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab.png"]];
```

Comment: Maybe you missing #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>. More information https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#installation

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
[newsImage.image sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[jsonResult[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab.png"]];
```

To

```
[newsImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[jsonResult[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If `newsImage` is your `UIImageView` then code should be as below.

```
[newsImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[jsonResult[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab.png"]];
```

> -(void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder

Above method is for `UIImageView` and you were applying this method to `UIimage` so it might crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this method on **imageView**, and not on **imageView.image**

Use this code :

```
[newsImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[jsonResult[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab.png"]];
```

Also don't forget to import

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code -

Add in your viewcontroler  - `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>`

```
[newsImage  sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[jsonResult[indexPath.row]
                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab.png"]
                          options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```